# magento + Warning: Illegal string offset 'value'

Tags: magento

In Payment Methods, when I changed magento store/website then below error message is showing

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'value'  in \app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form\Field.php on line 111

Please help me..

Comment: Have you get installed any new extension recently ?

Comment: What's your Magento version ?

Comment: @Nolwennig: magento 1.8 verson

Comment: it's look like than you get an empty sql result

Answer (score 2):

Just had this issue, which is caused by a third party module using the shop system config.

Look if there is any module that has a drop-down field in the configuration. The module must have a custom model that provides options for this field (this model extends the `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data` class, search the source code by it). It is likely that its `toOptionArray` function returns an array improperly formatted: its elements must be arrays with two keys, "**value**" and "**label**". If it is formatted differently, the warning will be logged, despite saving the config values correctly.